# National number format in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, language

I have MS Windows 7 and MS Excel 2013. I usually edit English documents but I occasionally need to edit and print documents in different languages (German, Russian, Czech). Excel gets decimal symbol and digit grouping symbol from windows language settings. They are `,` and `.` and it is fine when I edit an English document but when I open a document in different language I always need to change global windows setting to force excel use a proper decimal separator and proper digit group separator. And I do not want to switch windows language settings again and again just because I need to open and print a document in a local language.

How to set the decimal separator and digit number separator per excel document?

Answer (score 2):

Go to File in Excel 2013, Excel Options, Advanced, Editing Options The Paragraph with : Use System Separators

First remove the check for use system separators it will enable to change:
Decimal Separator and Thousands Separator you can write the symbol you want but remember always to write the same format for your numbers in order to use the formulas.

Here is the URL that explain it:
http://www.solveyourtech.com/change-decimal-separator-excel-2013/

Comment: +1 because settings in excel is better than global settings in windows. But not accepted because it still global settings for all excel documents. It is not a per document settings.